# Titanium android : unable to get the device token using com.activate.gcm module

Tags: android, push-notification, titanium, appcelerator, google-cloud-messaging

I am unable to get the device token in the success method of gcm.registerC2dm instead i am getting null or '' value of device token please help me regarding this if some one has idea.

I am using pushnotifications module : com.activate.gcm version 0.5 android sdk : 2.3.3 titanium sdk : 3.00 GA

Regards:Ali